# Send input from one threaded subprocess to another

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

main script starts the second script in a new subprocess and thread that continuously checks the stdout for data. The second script asks for input. I would like to have the first script ask for user input then pass it to the second script. I'm developing on windows and couldn't get pexpect to work.

test.py - main script

```
import threading
import subprocess

def read_output(process):
    print("starting to read")
    for line in process.stdout:
       print (line.rstrip())

def write_output(process,s):
    process.stdin.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
    process.stdin.flush()

process = subprocess.Popen('python test2.py', shell=False,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=None)

# Create new threads
thread1 = threading.Thread(read_output(process))

# Start new Threads
thread1.daemon=True
thread1.start()

s=input("test input:")
print("yep:"+s)
thread1.process.stdin.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
thread1.process.stdin.flush()
```

test2.py second script

```
print("Enter an input A,B,C:")

s=input("")
print("you selected:"+s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First mistake: wrong args when creating thread. You're passing the result of the function, called in the main process: the thread isn't started yet, you read the output in the main thread, not in the started thread.

Fix it like this:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=read_output,args=(process,))
```

Second mistake (or maybe that the program continues), you must close process stdin after writing a string in it:

```
process.stdin.close()
```

Fixed `test1.py` file:

```
import threading
import subprocess

def read_output(process):
    print("starting to read")
    for line in process.stdout:
       print (line.rstrip())


process = subprocess.Popen('python test2.py', shell=False,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=None)

# Create new thread: pass target and argument
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=read_output,args=(process,))

# Start new Threads
thread1.daemon=True
thread1.start()

s=input("test input:")
print("yep:"+s)

process.stdin.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
process.stdin.write("\r\n".encode('utf-8'))  # emulate "ENTER" in thread
process.stdin.close()  # close standard input or thread doesn't terminate
thread1.join()   # wait for thread to finish
```

Comment: Thanks for your help that fixed the issue and put me on the right track for success! Correct me if I'm wrong but the stdin is fine to remain open the issue is that the string send doesn't send \r\n characters with the captured input. adding another line `process.stdin.write("\r\n".encode('utf-8'))` everything works as expected and leaves the stdin open for additional writes. Or can you reopen stdin easily if you close it?

Comment: you're right. If you don't close immediately, you have to send CR+LF (that's what I tried first when I didn't see the thread params problem). If you close the input you cannot reopen it again, so that's when you're done with the program.

Comment: Ok I understand thanks for clarifying that saved me lots of headache. What is the comma for after the process in args=(process,)?

Comment: it's to define a tuple. Else it would be a single value within parentheses